# WebResourceResponse 304

Tags: android, http-status-code-304

I want to override shouldInterceptRequest method in WebClient to use ip instead of host in Android Webview.Everything is OK except when the statusCode is 304.
Please help me.

I try to get webview's caches to build a new WebResourceResponse to return, but I can not get caches.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.